# What's overriding my preferred size? (JPanel)

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, jcomponent

So I'm pretty new to GUI, and came across the problem that whatever I set my preferred size to ( via `setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height))` ) it adds `10` to both width and height.  I was wondering, why does this happen?  Yes I understand that it is "preferred size" but surely there is a way to prevent this.  I can fix it by simply subtracting `10` from width and height before passing it to the method, but I was wondering what was going on.

My (relevant) Code:

Main method:

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    final App app = new App(500, 500);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Block Stacker 3000");
    frame.getContentPane().add(app);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    System.out.println(app.getSize());
    app.start();
 }
```

App constructor (extends JPanel):

```
  public App(int width, int height)
  { 
     this.width = width;
     this.height = height;

     System.out.println(width + " " + height);

     setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width , height));

     setBackground(Color.CYAN);
  }
```

When run, it outputs the following:

```
500 500
java.awt.Dimension[width=510,height=510]
```

Also, I've tried using `setMinimumSize()` and `setMaximumSize()` but neither really affected anything.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work.  However, you comment got me messing around with the code a bit more, and I discovered that if I set the size with "setSize(500, 500);" then "setResizable(false);" and finally "pack();" it seems to work perfectly, but I'm not sure why.  It doesn't seem to work any other way.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Thanks, will do next time

Comment: [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513)?

Comment: *"will do next time"*  Will look at your question, next time.

Comment: Sorry, first question asked, I'm new to the site and I just now noticed the edit option for my question.  You don't need to be rude to point out ignorance.

Answer (score 3):

The size of your `JPanel` is going to be determined by the layout manager handling the components in its container.  `JFrame` has a default layout manager, so there is one even though you are not setting it.  Some layout managers pay attention to preferred size, some don't, some pay more attention to minimum/maximum size than others.

You can set a "null layout manager", also known as "absolute positioning", and control all the sizes yourself, but I would think you aren't trying to do that (since you are setting a "preferred" size).  What you will need to do to design your UI is figure out what relative sizes and positions you want things to have AND what you want to happen to them when the size of the window changes; that determines which layout managers go onto and into which container panels and the container panels that contain them, etc.

And I wouldn't eliminate `frame.pack();` it essentially tells the layout manager to do its stuff, and you usually WANT the layout manager to handle things once you get them set up the way you want them...

Answer (score 2):

I copied/pasted your code and got the following output:

```
500 500
java.awt.Dimension[width=510,height=530]
```

But then, I toke a screenshot of the frame:

[image]

If you download the picture and check the file properties, you will see that it is 502 pixels width (due to the window 1 pixel thin border) and 531 pixels height (due to the window title bar 31 pixels height), checking the image in gimp, I could find that the Cyan area is in fact **500x500** pixels wide.

**UPDATE:** Move the `setResizable(false)` sentence to the line after  `frame.setVisible(true);`:

```java
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Block Stacker 3000");
    frame.getContentPane().add(app);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setResizable(false);
```

After that, it will print:

```
500 500
java.awt.Dimension[width=500,height=500]
```

Comment: Yes, but the panel is still 510 by 530, you just can't see it because the frame is only 500 by 500.  When I try to add elements to the panel they extend off the screen.

Comment: I moved the `setResizable(false)` after the `frame.setVisible(true);` and it works, prints `java.awt.Dimension[width=500,height=500]` now.  Test it please

Comment: Tried it, and it works, but creates problems of it's own.  The frame is now larger than the panel, at least for me.  When I add `System.out.println(frame.getSize());` right before the call for the app size.  It returns `java.awt.Dimension[width=516,height=536]`  Very stange

Answer (score 0):

You must call `pack()` **after** calling `setResizable(false)`, because when window is resizeable, layout manager will leave 10px margin for (potential) scrollbars.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final App app = new App(500, 500);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Block Stacker 3000");
    frame.getContentPane().add(app);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.pack();

    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    System.out.println(app.getSize());
    app.start();
 }
```